# Saving both variable name and content into associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

Can i define an associative array using name and value of some variables at the same time and without looping in a simple elegant way?

I know it is possible taking variable names or setting it manually is not hard at all, but i think there might be a function to do this all at once. Or there should be one, but i didnt found any

Im looking a function similar to:

```
$ar_var= to_associative_array($name, $id, $start_date, $end_date, $status, $details);
```

... and  being able to print something like:

```
echo $ar_var['status'];
echo $ar_var[5];//Usually you would use this to access this data
```

... or a vardump showing something like

```
name => 'John Doe'
id => 'FX1678798Z'
start_date = > '27/03/2018'
status => 'delivered'
```

Comment: What you're asking is a bit unclear. You want a 2D array with associative arrays inside in the end ?

Comment: No, just a regular associative array. When you create an array it is automatically defined with numbers as indexes. I want to know if there is a function which captures the names of the variables to replace these numbers automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use compact() to accomplish this.

Assuming the variables you are using are declared and have assigned values, you can use it like this:

```
$ar_var = compact('name', 'id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status', 'details');
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/8jnCe

Comment: Perfect, that makes it. I didn't know that could take the reference to the variables as the parameters are "strings" but it does. Thanks a lot